# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException even though I set target SDK to android 1.6

Tags: android

I have an android project that is set to run on android 3.2, and I have a library project that uses networking in its main thread, which by sdk version of 3,2 throws android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. By SDK version below Honeycomb using network in main thread is ok: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html.

To solve this problem, I tried setting my library project's SDK version to 1.6, however the same error is still there! Is this normal behavior of Android? Isn't it wrong? What about backward compatibility?

Edit: I know that I should not perform a network request in main thread, however its not my code that does it, but the library that I have to use. I cannot/would not like to touch the code of the library, its a commercial API that belongs to other company.

Edit 2: I am of course trying to get a newer/fixed version of that library, but that is another issue. So my question now is, is there a way to compile/run the library with an older SDK?

Answer (score 2):

I think the bottom line is that if you try to run it on a 3.0+ device/ emulator it won't work. You need to use an AsyncTask.

Comment: I would, but the library project does not belong to me, and I would prefer not to hack it.

Comment: Its a broken library, have whoever built it fix it.

Comment: @HandlerExploit, I totally agree, but its easier to be told, than done:)

Comment: AsyncTask has been in Android since the Android 1.5.

Comment: Ah, a possible work around is that any call to that function should be put in an AsyncTask (Which are easy to use).

Comment: Although I've no idea of what library or how it works / is strutured

Comment: @Elchin I have had to deal with it in the past, it may not be the easiest thing to do but it is the best in this case. Let the developers who built it fix it so that it won't cause any other issues that might come back at you.

Comment: @Elchin "I would prefer not to hack it"... you're not "***hacking it***"... you're "***correcting it***". The library project you are using is clearly outdated... maybe you should rethink your strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The library project you are using *should not* perform network operations on the main thread. Android is throwing this exception because it is incredibly bad practice to do so.

**You should not hack your way around the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`**; use an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` to perform the network operations instead.

Read this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html) for more information.

Comment: I totally agree with you guys, but my situation is different. I edited my question with details.

Comment: @Elchin If you aren't willing to alter the source code in the library project, please try to find a new one. The bottom line is that you should not perform potentially expensive operations on the UI thread... the developer site mentions this in basically every article having anything to do with "implementing a responsive UI".

Comment: I am of course trying to do that. Until that works, is there a way to compile the library with older SDK?

Comment: The library becomes part of your application when you compile it, so you can't change the SDK version *only* for the library project. Your app (presumably powered by a more recent SDK) will invoke the library project using the more recent SDK methods, so you'll still get an `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.